# connecting to Robson server

Tags: javascript, web3js

Error attempting to connect to function of contract deployed to Robson server.

Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: {"size":0,"timeout":0}

This is my code.

```
const call = () => {
  const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xEF7D71764b5fe95f8584D70bF3B1Ead15CAF89eD";
  const address = "";
  const fundRasing = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
  fundRasing.methods.beneficiary().call({from: address}).then(console.log);
};
call();
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

It seems an issue with connecting to your server or an issue with `geth` (or the Ethereum client) configuration. But `web3.js` did not report the issue clearly.

And to confirm that the issue is with the `geth`  configuration (or the Ethereum client you are using), and how it is being accessed, try running `geth` with `--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0` and `--rpccorsdomain "*"`. And you are supposed to not face this error again. If this did not work try running `geth` on your local machine to be able to investigate.
However, it is extremely dangerous to have this mentioned configuration (`--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0` and `--rpccorsdomain "*"`). But I recommend you do this in a test machine to confirm the issue's root cause. But for a production environment, you would need different setups and configurations according to your exact case.

You nay follow up with the issue here: https://github.com/web3/web3.js/issues/5661#issuecomment-1332506572